# Easy partial path name search in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, search, ide, sublimetext, atom-editor

Currently there is the Open Resource dialog (Ctrl Shift R) in Eclipse, which is pretty great but lacks the following option:

Search for partial names in file paths without using the construct `*foo*/*bar*/somef`, but using the easier format with spaces such as `foo bar somef`. (I think this is how Sublime and Atom implement search when using the Ctrl P fuzzy finder, more or less).

For example the file `somedir/foothis/barthat/somefile.txt` will match this query.

Is there some way to achieve this? Remember this functionality is independent of file contents, file types or programming languages. No need to get complicated intelligent plugins on board (because they are half broken most of the time).

Final note, I'm aware of the Open Type / Type Browser dialogs, which are not exactly offering this functionality.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is already available in LUNA. Try it.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Running `Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)` and it does not seem to work.